# Convert UUID to string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, uuid

Can help to provide how to change from "67FE893C-C9F8-44AD-8CB1-00000D83CD48" to "67FE893CC9F844AD8CB100000D83CD48" in SQL Server, which is remove "-"? Just now I try to use this function `convert(nvarchar(50), Id)`, but the result is still showing "-".

Comment: `REPLACE(CONVERT(...), '-', '')`

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: In Google Big Query, there is no uuid allow, i need to check data in original database(sql server)

Comment: @HoneyBadger Thanks! It solved.

Comment: @John solved what? Why do you want to convert a GUID to a much larger string, and why remove the dashes? This won't make using GUIDs any easier. Indexing or comparisons won't work any better. If you want a string for display, the best place to format is on the client/display/report code, just like dates and decimals

Comment: This sounds a bit like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X (something to do with GUIDs) and assume Y is the solution (change them into strings). When that doesn't work, you ask about Y, not X. What is the actual problem? That `convert` can cause problems. Not only does it take more space for no benefit, if you try to filter a `GUID` field by converting to string, you *prevent* the server from using any indexes

Answer (score 0):

Use replace function.

```
select replace(COL_NAME, '-', '') from <TABLE_NAME>
```